# insert query symfony 2 without form

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, entity, dql

I'm working with Symfony 2 and I need to insert some data in a MySQL table. I know how to do it using a form:

```
$m=new table();
$form=$this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new tableType(),$m);
$request=$this->getRequest();
if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
{
    $form->bind($request);  

    if ($form->isValid())

    {
        $rm=$this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $rm->persist($m);
        $rm->flush();
    }
```

that works but I dont want to use a pre-defined form because I need complex control on my input. I need to generate the value with jQuery.
So how can I proceed to insert the values of my input into my table?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can pass the whole request to the action as following

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// <...>

public function fooAction(Request $request)
{
  $foo = $request->query->get('foo', 'default_value_for_foo'); // get the foo param from request query string (GET params)
  $bar = $request->query->get('bar', 'default_value_for_bar'); // get the bar param from request POST params

}
```

Also you might be interested in collection form types which can allow you to generate multiple rows or entities for form (not fixed)

Answer (score 0):

That's actually easier than using forms :D

```
<?php
// ...

// fetch your params
$m = new table();
$m->setWhatever($request->get('whatever'));

// persist
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$em->persist($m);
```

Note:

1. use camel-case PHP-class names: e.g. Table, NiceTable
2. `$form->bind` is deprecated I think, use `$form->handleRequest`
3. anyway if you need to validate your input, I recommend using validators and forms anyway. Setting up a model and validate it is quite smart. You don't need to create the view `createView()` of it of course, but the validation component in Symfony is very mighty :).

Comment: You forget the flush() after persist.